# How i can use If Else in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Inside a stored procedure i want to fetch list of customer based on input parameter in_customerid , if input customerid is not null or 0 then fetch all the customers where customerId equals to in_customerid otherwise select all customers.

I tried the code here and with case statement as well

```
select * from Customer
WHERE (IF in_customerId = 0 OR  in_customerId IS NULL 
   THEN customerId>0
   ELSE
    customerId=in_customerId
  END IF)
```

> if input customerid is not null or 0 then fetch all the customers
>   where customerId equals to in_customerid otherwise select all
>   customers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `nvl()` function with argument zero as `nvl(in_customerId,0)` to combine the cases for `in_customerId` for being null or zero :

```
SELECT * 
  FROM customer
 WHERE customerId = case when nvl(in_customerId,0) > 0 
                         then in_customerId 
                         else customerId 
                    end;
```

Another option uses [`nvl2()`](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/nvl2.php) function with `decode()` :

```
SELECT * 
  FROM customer
 WHERE customerId =  decode( in_customerId, 0, customerId, 
                             nvl2(in_customerId,in_customerId,customerId) );
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fee8b567c2cede0c4e76024e3ad975ad)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there with your code. Try this instead:

```
SELECT  *
  FROM  Customer
  WHERE ((in_customerId IS NULL OR in_customerId = 0) OR
        (in_customerId IS NOT NULL AND in_customerId <> 0 AND customerId = in_customerId))
```

This will return all customers where the `in_customerId` parameter is NULL.

In the case of `in_customerId` having a value, it will return matching rows only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE .. WHEN` expression, as you don't need any condition in case the passed parameter is null or 0 here as following:

```
SELECT  *
FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE
    CUSTOMERID = CASE
        WHEN IN_CUSTOMERID = 0
             OR IN_CUSTOMERID IS NULL THEN CUSTOMERID
        ELSE IN_CUSTOMERID
    END;
```

Cheers!!